# Similar question but not duplicate, answers not in the other question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate

I asked this question: [Why does du report a size of 0 for some non-empty files on a HFS+ partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96491/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-du-and-ls-for-some-files-on)

There is another question: [Directory size calculation difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19882/directory-size-calculation-difference) that also treats this kind of problem, with `du` and `ls` reporting different sizes for a file.

However, the problem is completely different in my question, and I found the answer with good references.

I know the questions look the same in surface, but mine is really HFS+ specific, and has the right answer (I think).

I don't really have the time to advocate for this question, as I already have the answer, but I know the answer is a bit tricky to find. Should I leave as it is ?

Answer (score 3):

When you voted to reopen it, it ended up in the reopen queue, so other people would've reviewed it and in theory helped you reopen it without the need for a meta post. On the other hand, I doubt they would've realized without further explanation why the question isn't a duplicate, so it probably wouldn't have reopened. In any case, it's open again

Comment: OK Thansks. I don't really know how SE works besides questions/answers/comments/accept and basic rep.

Answer (score 2):

When a question is mistakenly closed as a duplicate, it's usually because the difference is not as obvious as it should be. It is a good idea to edit the question to make the difference more apparent, for example by adding a sentence like “Unlike the situation in <link>, the widget I'm trying to frobnicate is not frilly”. It's best if the title includes something that establishes a distinction with the non-duplicate too.

I've edited the title here to make it more specific — the more common explanation for du and ls reporting different sizes would not justify du reporting 0.

Comment: Thanks, it's looking good now.